# Microsoft Access/SQL/Date Range/ when adding end date, query does not return results

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I'm having some troubles with the information below. Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Intake
WHERE ("Current Date") >= [Enter Start Date, mm/dd/yyyy]
AND ("Current Date") <= [Enter End Date, mm/dd//yyyy];
```

When I just do:

```
WHERE ("Current Date") >= [Enter Start Date, mm/dd/yyyy]
```

the query works wonderfully and the date range appears! But when I enter the second part:

```
AND ("Current Date") <= [Enter End Date, mm/dd/yyyy];
```

The query never returns a result. I am simply trying to query a date range on my database with user inputs. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Current Date" is date/time, short date. Not much of an expert, hope this helps

Comment: Then it sounds like either the date mask is wrong / not set on the form side, or there indeed are no records that match both criteria?

Comment: definitely records within the range. new database, added records just to test

Comment: oh yes! the Current Date of record 1 is: 10/12/2015

Comment: user input: 10/10/1999 - start, 01/01/2018 - end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Access does not use quotes for a field name - quotes are used to define a string.

You are comparing your date to text. A letter is after numbers so your **C** for "Current Date" will be after any date.

I forgot how to handle names with spaces in **Access** - I think you use brackets -

```
SELECT *
FROM Intake
WHERE [Current Date] >= [Enter Start Date, mm/dd/yyyy]
AND [Current Date] <= [Enter End Date, mm/dd//yyyy];
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208930(v=office.12).aspx